# How to show zoomed-in cell always at another fixed cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Im makeing a report overview sheet in Excel, to zoom-in the selected cell.

Right now Ive been able to make it work in top left corner of active cell, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to move the picture to the top left corner of a fixed cell.

```
Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Sub za zoom in celic D3:W39


Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xShape As Variant
Set xRg = Target.Areas(1)

If InRange(ActiveCell, Range("D3:W40")) Then

For Each xShape In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    If xShape.Name = "zoom_cells" Then
        xShape.Delete
    End If
Next
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(xRg) = xRg.Count Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xRg.CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Application.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
With Selection
    .Name = "zoom_cells"
    With .ShapeRange
        .ScaleWidth 2.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleHeight 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        With .Fill
            .ForeColor.SchemeColor = 44
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Solid
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With
End With
xRg.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set xRg = Nothing
End If
End Sub

Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
' returns True if Range1 is within Range2
InRange = Not (Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Contents of any active cell within the specefied range should zoom-in (already does) but it should display at a fixed location (lets say top left corner of cell X3).

Help would be appriciated since this is my first attempt at VBA.

Regards,
W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by simply adding `.Left` and `.Top` parameters..

Inside your existing code you have:

```
With Selection
    .Name = "zoom_cells"
    With .ShapeRange
        .ScaleWidth 2.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleHeight 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
```

Change it to:

```
With Selection
    .Left = .Parent.Range("X3").Left
    .Top = .Parent.Range("X3").Top
    .Name = "zoom_cells"
    With .ShapeRange
        .ScaleWidth 2.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleHeight 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
```

Comment: Thank you! Ive tried with versions of "img.Left = 50 img.Top = 150" but couldnt make it work proper.